# C -Snake Ncurses leaving trail when moving

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to get a better grip on how to create a snake Movement in C/Ncurses. One problem I am running into are the trails is leaves behind when moving to another direction. "Tailsize" will later be used to be increased when the snake grows but I set it to 3 for now so it can be seen what happens.

Below a basic function that I would like to get working first before I move on. Any tips on how to resolve this trailing when turning direction?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

void movesnake();

int main()
{
    int ymax,xmax; 
    int wymax,wxmax;
    int snake='O';
    int tail='O';
    int snakelocationy,snakelocationx;
    int input;
    int tailsize=3;

    initscr();
    noecho;
    getmaxyx(stdscr,ymax,xmax);

        WINDOW* border=newwin(ymax/2,xmax/2,ymax/4,xmax/4); 
        box(border,0,0);
        getmaxyx(border,wymax,wxmax);
        keypad(stdscr,true);
        keypad(border,true);

        snakelocationy=wymax/2;
        snakelocationx=wxmax/2;
            
   mvwaddch(border,snakelocationy,snakelocationx, snake);

    refresh();
    wrefresh(border);
    input=getch();
    
    while(1)
    {
        mvwaddch(border,snakelocationy,snakelocationx, snake);
        
        input=getch();
        
        movesnake(border, &snakelocationy, &snakelocationx, input, tailsize);
    
        refresh();
        wrefresh(border);
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;   
}

void movesnake(WINDOW* border, int *pSnakelocationy, int *pSnakelocationx , int input , int tailsize)
{
        if (input==KEY_UP)//up
        {
            mvwaddch(border,*pSnakelocationy+tailsize,*pSnakelocationx, ' ');
            (*pSnakelocationy)--;
        }
        else if (input==KEY_DOWN)
        {
            mvwaddch(border,*pSnakelocationy-tailsize,*pSnakelocationx, ' ');
            (*pSnakelocationy)++;
        }
        else if (input==KEY_LEFT)
        {
            mvwaddch(border,*pSnakelocationy,*pSnakelocationx+tailsize, ' ');
            (*pSnakelocationx)--;
        }
        else if (input==KEY_RIGHT)
        {
            mvwaddch(border,*pSnakelocationy,*pSnakelocationx-tailsize, ' ');
            (*pSnakelocationx)++;
        
        }   
}
```

Comment: Do you want your snake to change direction? `mvwaddch(border,*pSnakelocationy+tailsize,*pSnakelocationx, ' ');` If you don't move in same direction for at least `tailsize` steps, this will probably not hit the place where the snake was 3 moves before. You need to keep track of your move history and delete accordingly.

Comment: Aside: `noecho;` -> `noecho();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your snake moves it may twist and turn, and so the tail's position relative to the head is not always going to be *N* places away in a single direction.

You must maintain more *state*.

One way to achieve this is to use an array that holds each snake part. When the snake moves: starting from the tail, each snake part is updated with the values of the part one closer to the head. The head is updated to the newest position.

The screen is cleared, and redrawn, with the snake drawn as a single entity.

Here is a cursory example. You will note there is no restriction on which way the snake can turn, and nothing stops the snake from travelling through itself, or wandering off the screen. This is the next problem to solve (hint: keep track the the snake's *heading*, to know where it can and cannot go).

```
#include <ncurses.h>

#define SNAKE_HEAD '@'
#define SNAKE_TAIL 'O'

struct pos {
    int y;
    int x;
};

void update_snake(struct pos *s, size_t len, int kp)
{
    int y = 0, x = 0;

    switch (kp) {
        case KEY_UP:
            y--; break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            y++; break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            x--; break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            x++; break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    for (size_t i = len - 1; i > 0; i--)
        s[i] = s[i - 1];

    s[0].y += y;
    s[0].x += x;
}

void draw_snake(WINDOW *ga, struct pos *s, size_t len)
{
    mvwaddch(ga, s[0].y, s[0].x, SNAKE_HEAD);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++)
        mvwaddch(ga, s[i].y, s[i].x, SNAKE_TAIL);
}

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    halfdelay(1);
    curs_set(0);

    int ymax, xmax;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, ymax, xmax);

    WINDOW *game_area = newwin(ymax / 2, xmax / 2, ymax / 4, xmax / 4);

    keypad(game_area, TRUE);

    struct pos orig;
    getmaxyx(game_area, orig.y, orig.x);
    orig.y /= 2;
    orig.x /= 2;

    struct pos snake_parts[100] = { 0 };
    size_t segments = 10;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        snake_parts[i] = orig;
        snake_parts[i].x += i;
    }

    while (1) {
        int input = wgetch(game_area);

        if ('q' == input)
            break;

        update_snake(snake_parts, segments, input);

        wclear(game_area);

        box(game_area, 0, 0);
        draw_snake(game_area, snake_parts, segments);

        wrefresh(game_area);
    }

    delwin(game_area);
    endwin();
}
```